# Closure confusion with keyword 'this'

Tags: jquery, module, closures

Below is my module. I want to namespace 'Module' with self.
So inside the module I assign this to self. With this, inside closures I can call Module as 'self' instead of this, that's my idea. But it gives error;

How can I use self or any other variable name instead of the module name?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        var Module =  (function(sendTo){
            var self = this;
            return {
                init: function() {
                    console.log('start');
                    this.login(); //ok
                    Module.login() //ok
                    self.login() //TypeError: self.login is not a function

                },

                login: function() {
                    console.log('login');

                }
            }

        })(interface);

        Module.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `self` has the value `this` had when you created your object; it doesn't refer to your object. When you call `Module.init`, the usual mechanism of setting `this` to the object that the `init` property came from during the call sets in.

If you want to always refer to your object via `self`, assign the object you're creating to it, and then return that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        var Module =  (function(sendTo){
            var self = {                     // ***
                init: function() {
                    console.log('start');
                    this.login();
                    Module.login();
                    self.login();
                },

                login: function() {
                    console.log('login');

                }
            };
            return self;                     // ***

        })(interface);

        Module.init();
});
```

Note, though, that nothing outside your code can change either `self` or `Module`, so it's a bit redundant to have both identifiers for the same object. Also note that [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) is a built-in global that you're shadowing (it's another way to refer to `window`, with slight differences), so `self` may be confusing to other people working in the code.